# I'm trying to save the animation itself and not a render is that possible?

Tags: animation

ok so I'm not trying to save what the animation looks like I'm trying to save the animation itself so I can create a new one and go back to it later.

question is do I need to create a secondary file for a different animation, or can I save it some how?

Comment: You can create a new file, but you can also create a new Collection or create a new Scene, it really depends on your needs, for example do you plan to animate the same object, and does the copy of the object needs to stick the changes of the original? etc

Comment: yah I am animating the same object and I don't mind putting it in a collection or a new scene but was just wondering If it was possible to just save the animation

Answer (score 1):

Lolock's comment makes me realize that you may just want to save your action: Open your *Dope Sheet*, switch it to *Action Editor*, click on the shield icon which is for *Fake User*, it will make sure that your action will always be available even though it is not used by any object, then close the action (*X*), it will automatically create a new action, and you can click on the down arrow button on the left of the action name to have access to the actions list:

[image]

If you want another version of your object, for example if it needs to be part of another setup and another collection, select your object, give it an animation, duplicate your object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, make the original invisible in the *Outliner*. For the duplicated object open the *Dope Sheet*, switch it to *Action Editor* mode, maybe click on the *Fake User* button even though the action is used by the original object, and close the action in order to create a new one:

[image]

Comment: Instead of duplicating your objects which can bloat your project to death, you can also just hit the `Stash` button in the action editor so that it stores the action in the NLA editor without it still being used, and THEN make a new action. Don't forget to name the actions though.

Comment: Sure, I don't know much about what he wants to do. Not a fan of stash though, if you want to make sure that your animation is safe you can just press the Fake User button